# render :update do |page| is not working correctly with Rails3.X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I have the following in my routes.rb :

```
  match 'admins/approve' => 'admins#approve', :as => :admins_approve, :method => :post
```

In my admins_controller.rb I have :

```
def approve
  render :update do |page|
      page << "alert(" + params[:note] + ");"  
  end           
end
```

in my admins/index.html.erb :

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td class= "action_add_note">
        <%= form_tag admins_approve_path, :id => "form_note_#{user.id}", :remote=> true  do %> 
          <%= text_area_tag 'note' %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_function content_tag(:i, "", :class => 'icon-ok' ), 
                  "$('#form_note_#{user.id}').submit();", :class => "btn"%>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I know I can use button instead of function but it is not the case here , anyways whenever I submit it I get wrong path somehow and the following error :

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template admins/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/Apple/code/rails_pp/app/views"
* "/Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.1/app/views"
app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:11:in `approve'

Rendered /Users/Apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.6ms)
```

Comment: Plz note that i'm using jQuery and not prototype

Comment: what is your desired functionality here? are you trying to submit a note to the approve action and just have a javascript alert box with the note data?

Comment: ya it is not the end result i am looking for, but at least I can't make this work .. do you have any clue what is going on ?

Comment: ok it seems that with jquery will meed to create separate file approve.js.erb for example and do the logic there, but is the best way to include my ruby code inside js.erb file or on the controller ? like let's assume with params[:note] I want to update user User.update_attributes(:note => params[:note]), where am I supposed to put that ? in def approve in admin_cotroller or in the approve.js.erb file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the link_to_function and add this to your form_tag

```
<%= text_area_tag 'note' %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit %>
 <% end %>
```

In your admin controller

```
def approve
  @note = params[:note]
  current_user.update_attribute(:note, @note)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then create an approve.js.erb file

```
 alert("<%= j(@note) %>");
```